# Follow / Unfollow button on django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

I have a django follow system in which a user can follow other users and also unfollow them such like in instagram. In order to follow a user, the person has to visit someone's profile and press the follow button, if the user already follows that person then the user can press the unfollow button. Also in a profile there is a follower count whcih displays the number of followers a user has and a following count that displays the number of users that user is following(again like in instagram).

Well everything was almost done and I was just missing the follower count in which I added a signals.py file to do it. When that file was finished I realized that now the buttons are not working because when the user presses the follow button it doesnt follow the user. What can I do to make this buttons do their job which is follow and unfollow people? please any idea helps.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True, default='default.png')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)
    connection = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    follower = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    following = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followed")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="follower")

    @classmethod
    def follow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.add(another_account)
        print("followed")

    @classmethod
    def unfollow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.remove(another_account)
        print("unfollowed")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

views.py

```
def profile(request, username=None):
    profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    if username:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        profile_bio = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
        user = user[0]
        conn = profile.connection
        is_following = Following.objects.filter(user=request.user, followed=user)
        following_obj = Following.objects.get(user=user)
        follower = following_obj.follower.count()
        following = following_obj.followed.count()

    else:
        post_owner = request.user
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        profile_bio = Profile.objetcs.filter(user=request.user)
        
    args1 = {
        'user_obj':user,
        'conn':conn,
        'post_owner': post_owner,
        'user_posts': user_posts,
        'follower': follower,
        'following': following,
        'connection': is_following,
        'profile_bio': profile_bio,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)

def follow(request, username):
    main_user = request.user
    to_follow = User.objects.get(username=username)
    following = Following.objects.filter(user = main_user, followed = to_follow)
    is_following = True if following else False 

    if is_following:
        Following.unfollow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = False
    else:
        Following.follow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = True
    resp = {
        'following': is_following,
    }

    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender = Following.followed.through) # which list is changed
def add_follower(sender, instance, action, reverse, pk_set, **kwargs):
    followed_users = [] # list of users main (logged ) user have followed
    logged_user = User.objects.get(username = instance) # user who followed other users
    for i in pk_set:
        user = User.objects.get(pk = i)
        following_obj = Following.objects.get(user = user)
        followed_users.append(following_obj)

    if action == "pre_add":
        for i in followed_users:
            i.follower.add(logged_user)
            i.save()

    if action == "pre_remove":
        for i in followed_users:
            i.follower.remove(logged_user)
            i.save()
```

profile.html

```
<div class="header-item">
  followers: {{ follower }}
</div>
<div class="header-item">
  following: {{ following }}
</div>
{% if connection %}
  <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' user_obj.username %}">Unfollow</a>
{% elif not connection %}
  <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' user_obj.username %}">Follow</a>
{% endif %}
```

Any questions please let me know in the comments;)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: havent work in this project for a little while now @Louis but I bountied this same question somewhere in my profile, the answer might be there if you are looking for adding the follow functionality to your project, also this code is from a youtube video which I didnt really understood, the video project is in youtube search it as socialite django.

Comment: thnaks I'll do it @Juan